# How to pass a property into a kebab-case property?

Tags: vue.js

here is a simple component:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1k0suqy/6/)

```
Vue.component('hello', {
        props : ['personName'],
    render : function(createElement) {
        var self = this
        return createElement("span", "Hello " + self.personName)
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data : {
      name : 'Jobs'
    }
})
```

Now I'd like to refer that component as follow:

```
  <hello person-name="Steve"></hello> // works
  <hello person-name="{{name}}"></hello> // now working
```

I know v-bind works, any hints in the case of {{name}}? thanks

Comment: Why not use property binding? In vuejs you can't have attribute values through an expression.

Comment: was thinking it might be the same as angular

Answer (score 0):

You can have the variables in your data properties passed on as props or other attributes by using property binding:

```
<component :prop-name='value' />
```

where `:prop-name` is the property binding short-hand syntax.

1. Attributes with `:` i.e. property bound attributes, can access `vue` instance `data` properties, `methods`, `computed` properties.
2. Vue Directives on the other hand directly use the vue instance variables without the need of property binding. like:

   ```
   v-if='val > 0'
   ```

with your component setup like:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      val: '0'
    }
  }
}
```

[Your posted code](https://jsfiddle.net/u2myeh62/)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I know v-bind works, was just wondering if prop-name="{{name}}" works too.